# Is black American history only about segregation, slavery, and the 3 people you get taught about in school?

Tags: united-states, black-history

I'm a black eighth-grader, and I'm learning about slavery and stuff. But it hit me, in all of the time I've been learning history, I have only seen my people talked about (just in the book) if the topic is slavery, the teacher may talk about segregation and try to connect it with the history book somehow but that was in elementary. I guess you can't get too in-depth with the whole racism thing for 4th graders.

When it's black history month the school, both past, and present, does an attempt at representing my people, but each year I only learn about Rosa Parks, Martin Luther King Jr., George Washington Carver, and that's it (I learned about Harriet Tubman from a TikTok video so she was excluded). We have to write an essay about one of these people and blah blah blah, rinse-wash-repeat every year.

I don't know my heritage (knowing it won't do anything with me) so I'm focusing on American history.

**My question is, did black *American* history only have like 3 people, 4 if I'm generous, that were notable? And is black history only about slavery and segregation? Or is it my school that isn't teaching me about my culture.**

Comment: Try reading about [Robert Smalls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Smalls), [Lincoln Alexander](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lincoln_Alexander), [Buffalo Soldiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffalo_Soldier) and [Tuskegee Airmen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuskegee_Airmen) - just off the top of my head.

Comment: Welcome to History:SE.  As it stands, this is probably way too broad for the SE format. In short, "*did black history only have like 3 people, 4 if I'm generous, that were notable?*" **No, there were many, many more**. "*is black history only about slavery and segregation?*" **No, there is much more to it than that**.  "*is it my school that isn't teaching me about my culture*" **Without knowing the details of your school's curriculum, there is no way I (or anyone else) can answer that**.

Comment: A good starting point might be a Google search for `black history online resources`

Comment: In spring of 1918 Pershing was still reluctant to put American soldiers in combat against the Germans. But after the Black soldiers lent to the French proved themselves, it became embarrassing because to not do so would have admitted that the Black soldiers might just be better than the White boys.

Comment: I'm surprised Fredrick Douglass wasn't mentioned on that list. He's definitely an interesting person to read about if you don't already know his story.

Comment: @Chipster: Great addition. Nothing against Douglas - just my expertise is more military than social/political history, so he didn't jump to mind right away.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens I was referring to the OP's list, not yours. I certainly wasn't trying to imply you had something against Douglass. Sorry if I came across that way.

Comment: @Chipster: It didn't; and I didn't. I was kicking myself for not putting him on my list - but you caught the omission. OP: read up on [Mans Musa (c. 1280 – c. 1337)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mansa_Musa) also, thought by many to have been the richest man ever in history. He spent so much gold on his pilgrimage to Mecca that he caused massive inflation in his wake for decades after.

Comment: Also [Elijah McCoy](https://www.biography.com/inventor/elijah-mccoy), Black Canadian Inventor after whom the term ["*the real McCoy*"](https://www.orangeville.com/opinion-story/1483038-celebrate-black-history/) was allegedly coined due to the quality of his inventions and work.

Comment: @sempaiscuba My town doesn't really have the best school system (my district doesn't really care tbh) so maybe that's why. The schools are kinda iffy when it comes to the teachers for certain things, in third grade, I had only had substitutes for had 3/4 of the year. And then the teaching didn't consist of much, the history we learned was not about much in any topic, especially useless stuff when it came to the topic of black history. So it isn't surprising thinking about it.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens If you mean Mansa Musa then I have already learned about him in my school book, but the book didn't really say much. I will do more searching

Comment: American school curriculum could stand to improve representation.  I think we're getting better, but we're not there yet; sounds like your school trails a bit behind the average.  Is this report an opportunity for you to change that?  To write something that will improve representation?

Comment: The above is only "part" of black history. The other, equally important part, is about the history of Africans in Africa.

Comment: In addition to the fine comments above I'd also suggest that you study local and family heroes.  We don't all get a chance to make a national impact but each of us will be presented in our lives with a chance to make differences in our communities and our families.  These don't generally get written about in academic literature but to the few folks involved may be more "historic" than the folks you read about in text books.  Who is /your/ local hero?

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace I will use this for that, it will help I hope. I will email the superintendent of the district. Also, I will bring it up in my Thursday meeting (it will have both the 7th and 8th-grade class).

Comment: There is definitely a ton of cool black history, and [countless](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Black_Count/1N2S5K8KWeUC) [cool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_security#Origin) [black](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ralph_Bunche) [people](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Hidden_Figures/_upVjgEACAAJ?hl=en) to study. But I think it's also important to note that history is (mostly) written by the ones in control (i.e. rarely black people in US history), so there's probably even more that we don't know because of the oppression you described.

Comment: Local school boards are primarily responsible for development of US [curriculum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Education_in_the_United_States), but "In some states, textbooks are selected for all students at the state level, and decisions made by larger states, such as California and Texas, that represent a considerable market for textbook publishers and can exert influence over the content of textbooks generally, thereby influencing the curriculum taught in public schools,"

Comment: High school history tends to be terrible in general.  Doubly so when there is any whiff of controversy, so sadly what you end up with is all the interesting bits dropped, leaving something entirely sanitized.  There is a wealth of stuff out there, but you'll need to find it on your own.  (Or at the university level)

Comment: Haha this isn't just a Black American thing. I am from a White, Western country and it's a cliche that history in our schools is taught exclusively in terms of two events in our history - our war of independence and World War 2 - with all of the rest of our fascinating 2000-year-long history left out. Read, and read widely. And don't take anyone's opinion at face value - think critically and form your own opinions.

Comment: This is somewhat inflammatory but a lot of africans were sold by their local elite (or the neighbour's.)  It was a rather egregious type of farming. I'm thinking especially about Congo.

Comment: The cocoa boycotts ?

Comment: @StefanSkoglund How does that in any way relate to the question?  And if you're thinking especially about the Congo, *that* gets me to think mostly about Belgium or at least its homicidal king, Leopold 2.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica maybe they were replying to someone else or like they were talking about how slavery was a big thing in Africa so it would be black history. Also, how does the Congo relate to Belgium? One's in Africa and one's in Europe so I'm very confused.

Comment: In the late 1800s/early 1900s Leopold 2 of Belgium ran the Congo Free State as a particularly nasty and exploitative colonial venture, mostly for rubber and ivory.  Estimates of deaths are possibly in the 5-10M range.  Apocalypse Now, the movie was inspired by Heart of Darkness, the book which was written as a protest against Leopold's regime.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica  The cocoa boycotts ? or the rather extractive nobility in Congo ?  The cocoa boycotts were partly a result of the trade barriers  created in the great depression by  the big trading countries (particularly England and the US.)

Comment: @Fly-GooglyEyes  -  Just for clarity, did you mean to scope this to African-American/USA history?  (the tag is present, but the question seems open to global history.)  And thanks once again for a very active question.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace I was mainly asking about the black history of the U.S. Mainly because I know not all black people are African. Also because I don't know my ancestry. And no problemo.

Comment: @Fly-GooglyEyes - could you edit the question to reflect that; it is implied, but it isn't clear, and we've got one person who missed that assumption and answered the wrong question.  Thanks!

Comment: It was a bit out of scope for my answer, but I wanted to plug my favourite podcast. It's called *you're dead to me*. It's a BBC podcast, so don't know how easy it is to access from United States. But they have a great episode about Harriet Tubman. No doubt you know who she was, but for me at least there were which definitely some surprises - for example I didn't know that Tubman was so desperate to avoid detection she carried a gun to make sure none of the escapees tried to give the game away, or that she gave sleeping pills to children so they didn't cry and expose her. Worth a listen!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I wonder if it might not be useful to collate a set of links that could be provided to augment the school's curriculum.

## Significant individuals in Black history

### 18th Century and before

- [Crispus Attucks](https://www.revolutionaryspaces.org/exhibits/reflecting-attucks/reflecting-attucks-introduction/) and other [African American notables from the Revolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:African_Americans_in_the_American_Revolution)
- [Billy Lee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Lee_(valet)) - George Washington's valet. Arguably not the most significant individual in history, but he intrigues me because he broke up a fight between two white soldiers in New England; this meant that a black man laid hands on a white man and was not punished. This is an interesting example of the status of a black man and the meaning of enslavement.
- [Jean Baptiste Point du Sable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean_Baptiste_Point_du_Sable) - pioneer and entrepreneur
- [Toussaint Louverture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toussaint_Louverture).  Led the revolt of the Haitian slaves against France.  Captured by treachery and died in captivity.  In effect, he was the first Black statesman in the Western hemisphere.

### 19th Century

- [Robert Smalls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Smalls)

> Born into slavery in Beaufort, South Carolina, he freed himself, his crew, and their families during the American Civil War by commandeering a Confederate transport ship, CSS Planter, in Charleston harbor, on May 13, 1862, and sailing it from Confederate-controlled waters of the harbor to the U.S. blockade that surrounded it. He then piloted the ship to the Union-controlled enclave in Beaufort-Port Royal-Hilton Head area, where it became a Union warship. His example and persuasion helped convince President Abraham Lincoln to accept African-American soldiers into the Union Army.

- [Madame C.J. Walker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madam_C._J._Walker) and other [African American company founders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:African-American_company_founders)
- [Elijah McCoy](https://www.biography.com/inventor/elijah-mccoy) - It is alleged that [the phrase *The Real McCoy*](https://www.orangeville.com/opinion-story/1483038-celebrate-black-history/) was named after him, for the quality of his workmanship.
- [Andre Cailloux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andre_Cailloux) African American who served on *both* sides in the US Civil war and one of the first African American officers.

> "If ever patriotic heroism deserved to be honored in stately marble or in brass that of Captain Caillioux deserves to be, and the American people will have never redeemed their gratitude to genuine patriotism until that debt is paid." *[source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octavia_V._Rogers_Albert)*

- [Fredrick Douglass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frederick_Douglass), a former slave turned abolitionist.
- [Matthew Henson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matthew_Henson) - explorer
- [Bessie Coleman](https://www.biography.com/explorer/bessie-coleman) - pioneering aviatrix who preceeded Earhart.
- [Norbert Rillieux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norbert_Rillieux) - Franco-American chemical engineer and polymath

### 20th Century

- [Fredrick McKinley Jones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frederick_McKinley_Jones) -- Inventor of modern refrigeration
- [Lincoln Alexander](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lincoln_Alexander)  - 24th Lieutenant Governor of Ontario: September 20, 1985 – December 10, 1991 and other [Black Canadian politicians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Black_Canadian_politicians)
- [G. W. Carver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Washington_Carver) and other [African American inventors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:African-American_inventors)
- [Langston Hughes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langston_Hughes), [Phyllis Wheately](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phillis_Wheatley) and other [African American poets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:African-American_poets)
- [William Hastie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_H._Hastie) - lawyer and judge and other [African-American judges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:African-American_judges)
- [George McJunkin](https://www.texasmonthly.com/the-culture/texans-you-should-know-how-a-black-cowboys-discovery-changed-the-field-of-archaeology/) discovered the Folsom site and change archaeology.

### Additional resources

- [Wikipedia's big list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_African_Americans)
- Other [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:African-American_people) [lists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:African-American_engineers) (not linked in the big list)
- [Shetterly's big list](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Hidden_Figures/_upVjgEACAAJ?hl=en)

## Significant movements/events/groups in Black history

- [Reconstruction](https://www.crt.state.la.us/louisiana-state-museum/online-exhibits/the-cabildo/reconstruction-a-state-divided/index) - the reference goes to one of the more complex events in reconstruction; it is a symbol of the difficulty of understanding the complex interactions that characterized the post Civil War USA.  There is no simple way to tell this story, but it profoundly affected, and continues to affect,  African American civil life.
- [Buffalo Soldiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffalo_Soldier)

> the "Buffalo Soldiers" were established by Congress as the first peacetime all-black regiments in the regular U.S. Army.

- [369th United States Infantry](https://history.delaware.gov/african-americans-ww1/#:%7E:text=After%20the%20declaration%20of%20war,had%20registered%20for%20military%20service.)

> ...  in early 1918, the 369th United States Infantry, a regiment of African-American combat troops, arrived to help the French Army. Earning the reputation from the Germans as “Hell Fighters,” the 369th was nicknamed the “Harlem Hell Fighters” because the regiment “never lost a man through capture, lost a trench or a foot of ground to the enemy.” The 369th was also the first to reach the Rhine River and provided the longest service of any regiment in a foreign army. They fought in the trenches for 191 days and the entire regiment received the Croix de Guerre medal for their actions at Maison-en-Champagne.

- [Tuskegee Airmen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuskegee_Airmen)

- [1st Rhode Island](https://www.blackpast.org/african-american-history/first-rhode-island-regiment/#:%7E:text=The%201st%20Rhode%20Island%20Regiment,of%20African%20Americans%20in%201778.) and the [Marblehead Regiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/14th_Continental_Regiment)
- [Black](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Economic_Co_Operation_Among_Negro_Americ/qrM5tAEACAAJ?hl=en) [co-ops](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Collective_Courage/hDGnAwAAQBAJ?hl=en)
- [Black Cowboys](https://www.smithsonianmag.com/history/lesser-known-history-african-american-cowboys-180962144/)
- Artistic movements:

  - [Chicago Black Renaissance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicago_Black_Renaissance)
  - [Afrofuturism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Afrofuturism)

## Challenges in black historiography

- America’s always had black inventors – even when the patent system explicitly excluded them *[Conversation](https://theconversation.com/americas-always-had-black-inventors-even-when-the-patent-system-explicitly-excluded-them-72619)*, [Lisa Cook Working Paper](https://lisadcook.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/pats_paper17_1013_final_web.pdf)

---

Let's assume that the school's neglect of black history is due to resource constraints (not enough time to develop curriculum) and help out.  Marking this community wiki so that folks can add others.

Comment: It's kinda bad how the only person on this list I know is George Washington Carver, but who knew that so many black people were influential like that?

Comment: That is precisely why I think your question is important  - we've only scratched the surface.  Can you use any of this in the report you'll present?

Comment: Separate comment because I'm trying to figure out how to say this; while slavery remains a pervasive and possibly dominant feature in black history, wouldn't it be nice if black history included the entire scope of historical actions by African Americans?  Still struggling how to say that.

Comment: I think that you could say it like this "Slavery is a very big feature in black history since it was a very important time in history altogether, but it would be great if that wasn't the only thing that people try to make black history about and looked at other brighter aspects of black people that made history."                       
     And I would say yes, it would be great if they went to other aspects of black history and focused on those as well.

Comment: I totally forgot about Bass Reeves. Excellent choice to put on here.

Comment: I had never heard of Robert Smalls,  thank you for posting about him, what a fascinating story.  if anyone deserves a movie made of their life it is him.  I teared up a bit when his wife said to him, " “It is a risk, dear, but you and I, and our little ones must be free. I will go, for where you die, I will die"

Comment: ["The real McCoy"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_real_McCoy) - `The phrase "The real McCoy" may be a corruption of the Scots "The real MacKay", first recorded in 1856 as: "A drappie o' the real MacKay", ("a drop of the real MacKay"). This appeared in a poem Deil's Hallowe'en published in Glasgow and is widely accepted as the phrase's origin.`

Answer (score 4):

Black history, sometimes known as "African Studies" or "Africana," has at least two distinct elements. [An example](https://catalog.upp.pitt.edu/preview_program.php?catoid=188&poid=57488&returnto=17736) comes from the course catalog of the University of Pitsburgh, the city where I grew up.

The first, and more common, element is close to what you said. That is, African-American history, which consists largely of America's shameful legacy of "segregation, slavery, and the 3 people you get taught about in school," and the aftereffects of those issues, the effects of which persist until today.

The second, more hopeful element, is African history. Yes, African history was also tied up in some ways to the slavery of black people from west Africa in the western hemisphere, or by Muslims in northeast Africa. But there is also the story of black people who were allowed to remain in Africa, and who got "some" benefits (as well as many harms), from their experience with European colonialism. These include "coming" countries like Algeria, Egypt, Nigeria, South Africa, and probably others that I haven't mentioned. Some of these countries are overcoming their earlier hardships, and are placing themselves in a position to become "the countries of tomorrow."

Comment: Within the US context I would add that there is also plenty of interesting social history that is not entirely about dealing with oppression. I'm honestly not sure that you can do much of any US history without spending a lot of time dealing with white supremacy, but for example there is plenty of cultural history, intellectual history, place-based history, history of how people lived, biographical stuff, that is not directly about oppressive institutions. In a school context I tend to think that the oppression stuff is the most civically important, but it obscures the other stuff sometimes.

Comment: @capet:The point I was trying to make was that even the positive aspects of Afro-American history, e.g. the Harlem Renaissance, was shaped by the culture of "slavery and segregation" (IMHO). That is less true (although not totally untrue) for much of Africa.

Comment: Good point! I just don't want to make it sound like all African-American history is only about dealing with oppression; there's a lot more going on, within that context. Of course it would be even worse to make it sound like an any African-American history doesn't involve dealing with oppression to some degree. Harlem Renaissance stuff is a great example; it was reacting to oppression, but also was expressing all kinds of other creativity that people had.

Comment: What's the connection of Algeria or Egypt to Black history of the US? The majority population in both countries is Arab or Berber-Arab.Their experiences with slavery, historically often being slavers themselves (including the enslavement of Europeans ) and colonialism seem very different to sub-saharan Africa and have, as far as I know, little historical connection to the US.

Comment: @R.K.:Algeria and Egypt are at least "somewhat" black. As such, they are part of my argument that "black" history includes African, as well as U.S. blacks.

Comment: @TomAu Are there any signficant historical events or people that one could look into for Egypt or Algeria in relation to Black history on a high school level? Black citizens in both countries seem to be estimated at less than 3% of the total population (i.e. lower than in e.g. France or the UK) and other than maybe the far northern extent of the Kushites, I can't think of any good examples.

Comment: @R.K.: You're probably right that Algeria is technically non-black, but it appears to be part of "black history" https://www.blackhistorymonth.org.uk/article/listings/region/oxford/a-history-of-algeria/. Plus, a recent Miss Algeria is black. https://www.bbc.com/news/world-africa-46810367. Regarding Egypt, the main black influences appear to be the Kushite and Nubian kingdoms.

Comment: I think you need to make a distinction between modern and ancient Egypt there.

Comment: Also, I don't think that we should shy away from US history because things outside the US may be "more hopeful".  IMHO, both understanding and changing the modern use experience *requires* a deep knowledge of how we got here.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers have mentioned a lot of other people and events that your school should have told you about. I'm going to tackle this from a slightly different angle, and try to explain why you're experiencing this problem - and you are definitely not imagining it.

You summarised the curriculum as segregation, slavery and 3 civil rights icons. Believe it or not, the curriculum you're being provided represents an advance on what it was like before. It did not used to be a sympathetic portrayal, of civil rights heroes, and black people's defeat of *de jure* segregation. Not even a superficial one.

Until the 1930s, the [Dunning school](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning_School) of post-Civil War American history was academically dominant. A summary of this school:

> All agreed that black suffrage had been a political blunder and that the Republican state governments in the South that rested upon black votes had been corrupt, extravagant, unrepresentative, and oppressive. The sympathies of the "Dunningite" historians lay with the white Southerners who resisted Congressional Reconstruction: whites who, organizing under the banner of the Conservative or Democratic Party, used legal opposition and extralegal violence to oust the Republicans from state power. Although "Dunningite" historians did not necessarily endorse those extralegal methods, they did tend to palliate them. From start to finish, they argued, Congressional Reconstruction—often dubbed "Radical Reconstruction"—lacked political wisdom and legitimacy.

It wasn't until the 1960s that the Dunning school was discredited, and not until the 1970s that new interpretations emerged. The two interpretations now current are essentially a) that reconstruction was a good but failed attempt to remedy injustice, and that civil rights legislation has fulfilled its potential, or b) reconstruction failed because it was inadequate, and civil rights legislation still has not realised racial equality because it hasn't gone far enough.[2](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2701693) From the 1970s to the present day, a) was more influential in school because it was less controversial and more palatable ('it was bad but everything's fine now'), and that's essentially what the system is trying to sell you.

School history curricula are inevitably simplified versions of academic history's consensus, but they also tend to lag behind it. This might help to explain why people like Donald Trump, who went to school in the 50s and 60s, say things like the Civil War was a failure to compromise, as if Abraham Lincoln was somehow partly to blame for opposing slavery (I'm not making excuses for Trump -- most people of that era would think a bit more critically instead of repeating the propaganda of their youth). Likewise, the idea that the civil rights era made everything fine now is looking a bit ridiculous, but your curriculum has not yet caught up.

As you've noted, although shallow, the current history curriculum celebrates Martin Luther King and other civil rights heroes. Obviously the civil rights era led to this change -- the Dunning school was a tool for entrenching segregation. Most people would agree that a curriculum which celebrates MLK is less noxious than one that celebrates [Robert E Lee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_E._Lee). However, this leads to my next point: the study of history shouldn't be employed to celebrate a national story, however benign.

This [article](https://doi.org/10.1080/03050060020020444) is a comparative study of history education in the USA and Northern Ireland. It's about primary school (elementary school), but the observations are still relevant.

> The differing nature of historical representations in the two countries, however, leads students to contrasting conclusions about the purpose of learning about the past: in the USA, students emphasise that history is important so that they will know about the origin of their country and their own place within it, while in Northern Ireland students describe the purpose of history as being to learn about those who are different from themselves.

> These students consistently used pronouns such as ‘ our’ and ‘ we’ in talking about history; for them, history was important because it helped them understand how their country began and how they should treat each other. Reflecting the family contexts in which they had learned about the past, students thought they would one day hand this information down to their own children. But these were not the reasons students in Northern Ireland gave for studying history…
>
> [T]he most frequent reason students gave for learning history was nearly the opposite of US students’ rationale: history is important in order to learn about people who are different. Year 8 student Hamish put it succinctly— he said that history is important ‘to understand the way other people lived and went about their daily life’ . This theme ran throughout students’ explanations of the rationale for studying both particular topics in history and the subject in general; they consistently pointed to differences between past and present— the more differences the better— as the reason for their interest in history.
> …
>
> In the USA, the history that students encounter in public forums (whether schools, museums or cartoons) is almost always a story of national development: students learn about the original inhabitants of the Americas, their conquest by European explorers, the colonisation of the Eastern seaboard, the fight for independence from Britain and the development of the new nation— increasing prosperity, industrialisation, geographic expansion and the extension of rights and opportunities to new sections of the population.
>
> The historical figures children encounter from a young age are people who play a role (albeit sometimes mythical) in this story of progress and national development— Christopher Columbus, George Washington, Betsy Ross, Abraham Lincoln and Martin Luther King. Sometimes the nation’s past is presented in a positive light, and sometimes it is portrayed more critically— but whether positive or negative, history in the USA is invariably the history of us, the history of our nation. Learning about others— about medieval Europe or ancient China or the Malian empire or even the Aztecs— is rarely a part of young children’ s encounter with history; such peoples are not often represented in school.
> …
> At the same time, US educators must consider the limitations of history that focuses too exclusively on identity. Stories of who we are typically also become stories of who we aren’t: establishing loyalty to a community usually means denying others as lying outside that group. Such exclusiveness may be useful when trying to establish pride in the unique experiences of a particular community, but when the past of an entire nation is under consideration, narratives which focus only on limited sections of the population will exclude many whose experiences deserve to be recognised.
>
> In the USA, the story of the nation’ s past has for too long ignored or minimised the role of women, minorities and working people, and as a result national history— and national identity— have been equated with the limited interests of a small segment of its citizens. In this study, students’ explanations that studying immigration and the Civil Rights movement teaches us how to treat them suggests the limited horizon of their sense of American identity.

Another article (same author and topic, but [different article](https://doi.org/10.18546/HERJ.01.2.03)) shows the consequences of the US approach to history education:

> Based on this research, students in Northern Ireland appear to have a more developed understanding ofthe role of historical evidence than do students in the US. Most of the US students in these studiesappeared to treat historical sources simply as information, a perspective also identified among some English children in the work of Shemilt (1987) and Lee, Ashby, and Dickinson (1996). US students thought that people in the past knew what was going on around them, and they passed that information along to us, either through oral transmission or through books. Even when students talked about the use of physical remains and artefacts, they treated such remnants of the past simply as sources of information. They thought that old uniforms or muskets would show what old uniforms or muskets were like, but there was no suggestion that these could be used inferentially as evidence for a historical account. Historical sources, then, were simply seen as a means of direct access to the past. Although many students in Northern Ireland also saw oral transmission (but not books) as a source of knowledge, they typically combined this with a recognition of the role of other sources. Moreover, the way they referred to these other artefacts and remains indicated at least an initial understanding that they could be used as evidence, not simply as sources of information.

I am not suggesting that history teachers or education officials in Northern Ireland are morally or intellectually superior. There is a reason they've focussed their curriculum on distant times and places, as these articles note, and it's not because they can do more intellectually sound history. It's because the history of Northern Ireland is literally [explosive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Troubles), and history educators understandably don't want to prod it. It's a happy (and surprising) coincidence that this unhappy situation leads to more robust history education. I'm from the UK and a former teacher - US educators certainly aren't alone facing pressure to shape history education to the requirements of exceptionalist propaganda. [Things have got worse](https://conservative-speeches.sayit.mysociety.org/speech/601441) in England in that regard; it's a longstanding problem in [Japan].[8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_history_textbook_controversies)

You've astutely spotted some of the holes in the history education you're being provided. My advice would be: try not to think of history as just a story of how things came to be as they are. Learn about the past for its own sake, and it will benefit you in ways you didn't expect. How are you supposed to know what you need to know, until you know it?

Answer (score 0):

Good question and it is regrettable that you have good cause to feel that way.

First, you're probably right, you are going to hear about those 3 or 4 people for a while.  A big part of it is that, historically, the US, like most Western countries (and currently possibly quite a bit less than some) was run by white people.  So, going in back in history, there are fewer influential black people to talk about (or other ethnic groups, for that matter).  I'm sure that digging around others can and should be found - several good suggestions have been made.  I'd add whoever can be considered most influential in the early evolution of jazz, blues and rock and roll - after all that completely changed music for pretty much everyone *and* it impacted segregation as well.

But you have good reasons to feel excluded.  So, past history is kind of a loss there.

However, things are changing for the better.  President #44, Obama, was black.  President #47 *might* end up as Kamala Harris, if Biden wins but doesn't last the whole term.

When covering Obama in the future, should he be counted in Black History?  What about all the elected politicians like mayors, congress folk and governors?  They could.  Or they could just be covered as capable politicians who happen to be black.  Either way, I think your children will have a more inclusive history to study.

What about Africa?  Well, first US high school teachings tend to be very US centric, with a bit of Europe dashed in, maybe.  White preferences, again, to be honest.  Second, if you go back further than say 400-500 years there is a lack of written records, just like there would be when studying Native American cultures, so there is only so much history to cover *and* individuals' names aren't going to be much of a part of it, with some notable [exceptions](https://www.businessinsider.com/mansa-musa-the-richest-person-in-history-2016-2).  In any case, those would be more college-level courses.

Comment: Harris is more East Indian than Black, and graduated high school from Westmount in downtown Montreal, the very wealthiest bar none community in Canada at the time (though since eclipsed by the likes of Rosedale and Lawrence Park due to the post 1976 exodus of Anglos from Quebec). She is despised by most black not only for her pretenses at being black but also for her despicable record as a D.A. in California. What a terrible example to put up.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens BTW I know and don't approve of her tough-on-crime stint in California.  But your claim that she is despised is your claim and not [universally supported](https://www.bbc.com/news/election-us-2020-53746551) and https://www.cbc.ca/news/world/kamala-harris-dnc-1.5693168.  And WTF does "more East Indian than Black" mean on someone with a parent of each race?  That you have to be poor to be black?

Comment: @PieterGeerkens It's a bit odd to highlight a few years in Montreal for someone with deep roots in Oakland and Berkeley, and who went to Howard.   From what I've seen, the groups in the SF Bay Area that dislike her record as D.A. are best described as "progressive", not as "black".

Comment: That said, there are far more interesting things to be studying under the rubric of "black history" than modern politicians.  If I could mandate a book for a high school history class, it would be something like [The Warmth of Other Suns](https://www.amazon.com/Warmth-Other-Suns-Americas-Migration-ebook/dp/B003EY7JGM/ref=tmm_kin_swatch_0?_encoding=UTF8&qid=&sr=).

Comment: Sure, she's from an upper-middle class family.   But as someone whose been in the Bay Area for her politically active period here, the characterization seems quite alien.  There's a lot of room between "not connecting" and "despise".

Comment: "As someone", I mean me.  I've lived in the Bay Area since the early 90s.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica: You opted to bring toxic current politics into a History answer. Check the mirror. I couldn't care less what colour Harris is - but many look askance at her very very privileged upbringing in contrast to her constant claims of growing up poor. She's a fraud.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens First, I wasn't merely referring to this.  Rather, I've noticed a pattern where, when I interact with you in ways that do not suit you, downvotes mysteriously appear.  If I noticed it, I'm sure others have too.  Second, my answer to the OP was based on stating that *future* history books will have more black people in them, because black people are becoming more prominent in society.  I cited Harris as an example, not as an endorsement.  And frankly I am not interested in tracking whom you do/do not approve of and am doing my best to avoid you as much as possible.

Comment: @GorttheRobot  I wasn't suggesting that modern politicians be studied *now*.  Merely communicating to the OP that more black people will start appearing in history books in the future because US society is becoming less white-centric.

Comment: I kinda disagree.  The African American experience of the last few hundred years is a core part of what made the American nation what it is like today, and you don't necessarily need to study particular people to learn about that.  I think often people like the sort of feel-good nature of a biography in contrast to some of the lest pleasant history of what happened to people not so famous

Comment: @GorttheRobot The OP is specifically asking about **other** coverage of black **individuals** than oppression and slavery.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica You can't avoid someone on a forum, you know that right? No hate, that just struck me as odd since you said that you have a will of avoidance to Pieter (and it's the internet, privacy and avoidance can't be fulfilled most of the time). Personally, I don't know if they'll talk about them, I don't really learn much about presidents anymore and have no clue how much time has to pass to talk about them legally. Also, the presidency of blacks isn't my concern, since if in a book they wouldn't talk about the good and bad of said president since it's modern it'd be biased.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica Also, I don't think many modern politicians don't interest me since I always know that my people will be excluded and the others around me will be acting weird (hopefully, we might get a ton of money!) so what I said was biased in a sense lol. I'm so sorry if I offended you, that was not the intent if you were.

Comment: @Fly-GooglyEyes For now, are you mostly interested in individual people who were famous/influential/interesting? Sorry if you already answered this.

Comment: @Fly-GooglyEyes  No problem, not offended in the least.  Like I said past history is going to be a bit sparse on non-white people.  The state of current presidents and politicians is *not* an answer to your concerns.  But more people of color are starting to assume roles of historical significance that will be covered in history books at some point.  As to avoiding people on forums:  well, it sometimes works when you tell them you really rather not deal with them, rather than engaging in back-and-forth feuding.  There are plenty of other interesting people and insights around.

Comment: @capet you are correct my friend, politicians are not my priority at the moment. (I love a lot of musicians but those I know a lot about those).

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica Oh I see, so they will be covered in time but I wonder how they will be described in the books lol. For the forums: I think that just not engaging would be best, some people are fired up for a fued.

Answer (score 0):

My fifteen cents to black history:

Rome:

- [Septimius_Severus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Septimius_Severus) - the first black Roman Emperor.
- [Pescennius_Niger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pescennius_Niger) - another one

maybe more...

Egypt:

There are bunch of theories, who was this peoples, however, we have many statues:

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

You could read this page of wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_pharaohs

Comment: The question is tagged {united-states}; these examples are quite good for global black history.  I'll ask OP if the intent of the question is limited to USA.  (You're right - I particularly like Septimus Severus as an example.

Comment: Oh, my bad. Sorry. But black Rome Emperor - is awesome, let it be?